# Arrow keys "scroll" up-down and left-right instead of moving cell selector in Office Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

It happened all of a sudden (upon starting Excel).

I checked that it does it in all my Excel documents.

Answer (score 0):

I did accidentally press the 'scroll lock' key on my keyboard, which caused the issue.